# SQL Server Service can't start due to lack of permission

Tags: sql-server

I already run a default instance of SQL Server 2014, then I installed SQL Server 2016, but the SQL Service can not start.

This is the event log:

[image: event log for SQL Service can't start]

But the SQL Server 2014 instance was started with the similar user.

How to get this work?

Answer (score 0):

Run services.msc (press Windows + R then input services.msc). Scroll to the service, then right click it to open Properties dialog. Switch to tab Log On and change the user to log on to Local System. And then you can start the service
[image: set log on user]